# React Native - Global screen outside React-Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

In my React Native application, I am using Redux to manage the global state of the app. This is what the render of my `App.js` looks like:

```
render() {
   return (
     <Provider store={store}>
       <MainNavigator />
     </Provider>
   );
}
```

where `<MainNavigator />` exports `createAppContainer(createBottomTabNavigator({ ...my panel names }))` and `<Provider ... />` is imported from `react-redux`.

Everything works just fine. However, I would like to have a "global" screen which is independent of my navigator. I would like to have it mounted all the time immediately after the app has been launched and display it over the main navigator or hide it using Redux.

As an example, I am aiming to achieve something like the music screen on Spotify and SoundCloud which is always mounted while browsing through the whole app. Or as another example, the video screen on YouTube which serves the same purpose as the previous examples.

I have tried the following in my `App.js`:

```
render() {
   return (
     <Provider store={store}>
       <GlobalScreen />
       <MainNavigator />
     </Provider>
   );
}
```

However, this would split my application into two halves where the upper half of the screen displays the `<GlobalScreen />` component and the lower half displays the `<MainNavigator />` component.

How can I achieve a "global" screen, independent of React Navigation, which can overlay it or hide itself using Redux?

**P.S.** I am not sure if this can be achieved by having the screen outside React Navigation. But I am open to any suggestions which could help me achieve my desired goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional to render either the GlobalScreen or the MainNavigator.

```
{someConditionBasedOnDataFromStore ? (
  <GlobalScreen/>
):(
  <MainNavigator/>
)
```

You probably want this logic inside a component which connects to the store to get the data for your conditional.